# wamp collision after uninstall xampp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have an issue with wamp after uninstall xampp. When I run testmysql.php I will get this

```
Could not connect to MySQL: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

There are two warnings and one "deprecated" warning about mysql_connect(). Can be it meant as a depracated function (not supported in newer php versions..just old test file) as the warning said or is there really problem? Thanks for answers!

Comment: What colour is the wampmanager (W) icon that sits in the system tray?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes `mysql_connect()` is deprecated, simply use `mysqli_connecy()` instead.

Comment: There is a bit more to it than that, this makes it sound like its a simple one line change when its not. The whole mysql_* extension library has been deprecated!